# How to check Programmatically internet speed/bandwidth in vc++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-c++-2010

i want to check check internet speed/bandwidth of my computer in vc++ how should i check it? is there any wmi class there in vc++ for getting speed of internet or function/api which gives internet bandwidth/speed?

Answer (score 1):

The [Win32_PerfRawData_Tcpip_NetworkInterface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394340%28VS.85%29.aspx) raw performance data class provides raw data from performance counters that monitor the rates at which bytes and packets are sent and received over a TCP/IP network connection. It includes counters that monitor connection errors.